# use of 'load_img' requiers PIL and pillow is installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was training a model for images using tensorflow and keras.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=8000, #batch_size
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_steps=800 # batch_size
)
```

I got this error:

```
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

Pillow is already installed in my `conda` environment.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you actually import PIL.Image inside your environment?

Comment: You mean directly in terminal right! Yes, its not showing any error.

Comment: Or inside your keras script, it is not just about being installed, if PIL.Image errors while importing you would get the same message from Keras.

Comment: What can be the problem then?

Comment: Can you please share how are you loading the images? Are you using load_img function?

Comment: Thank you @Rohit for reviewing the question, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the environment as below if you are not specific to the versions

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow keras numpy pandas sklearn pillow
```

But if you are specific to versions then

```
pip install pillow
```

Note: If only install pillow then you need deactivate and reactivate the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Anaconda navigator > Environments > tensorflow > not installed > search for pillow >click on pillow and install it 
after then launch spyder or notebook again then it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

I installed the lates Pillow version (10.0.1) in my virtual environment and after deactivating and reactivating the environment, the issue was resolved.